# Error in JSON.parse in Jquery because of double quotes in value

Tags: jquery, json

I have this type of data response:

```js
'{"testID":"70000001","keyA":8,"keyB":16,"keyC":[{"cash":"{"end":2275,"cnt":52,"start":2223}"}],"pending":{"ew":30}}'
```

I believe the issue is because of this part:

```
"cash":"{"end":2275,"cnt":52,"start":2223}"
```

This is because when I remove this part, I was able to read the value for `pending.ew`. I cannot use `JSON.parse()` directly, even after I `JSON.stringify()` first. I am unable to read the `pending.ew` value.

Comment: You're correct, the error is because of the nested JSON string. You need to either escape the `"` within that nested JSON, or amend the format so it's part of the outer JSON string. I'd suggest the latter. Nesting JSON is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Do you have any idea how to escape ```"``` part because I can't change the existing JSON format return by other party?

Comment: You could hack something together with a regex, but it's very far from an ideal solution; the client side should not be responsible for fixing server side stupidity. Your best approach would be to contact whoever created that terrible response and tell them to fix it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks @RoryMcCrossan. I should do that instead.